# Convertir String a fecha con formato específico

Tags: java

Tengo dos atributos, uno de tipo fecha y otro de tipo hora.

Quisiera unir el día de la fecha y la hora y minutos de la hora y obtener un objeto `localdatetime` con un formato así:

> 16-12:34

Este es mi código:

```java
    package exercise9;

    import java.time.LocalDate;
    import java.time.LocalDateTime;
    import java.time.LocalTime;
    import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
    import java.util.Locale;

    public class Test {
        /* Class Attributes */
        private Subject       subject;
        private String        description;
        private LocalDate     date;
        private LocalTime     startTime;
        private LocalTime     endTime;
        private LocalDateTime key;

        /* Formatters for Date and Time class */
        DateTimeFormatter dateFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/LL/yyyy");
        DateTimeFormatter keyFormatter  = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd-hh:mm");

        /* Class Constructors */
        public Test(Subject subject, String description, String date, 
                   String startTime, String endTime) {

            this.subject     = subject;
            this.description = description;
            this.date        = setDate(date);
            this.startTime   = setTime(startTime);
            this.endTime     = setTime(endTime);
            // Inicializa el valor del atributo key con los
            // valores de date y startTime. Genera un
            // objeto LocalDateTime
            setKey();
        }

        /* Este método inizializa el valor del atributo 
         * date con la cadena pasada en el constructor
         * si cumple con el patrón de dateFormatter. */
        private LocalDate setDate(String date) {
            return LocalDate.parse(date, dateFormatter);
        }

        /* Este método inizializa el valor de los 
         * dos atributos LocalTime de la clase con 
         * los Strings pasados al constructor. */
        private LocalTime setTime(String time) {
            return LocalTime.parse(time);
        }

        /* Inicializa el valor de key con el día de
         * date y la hora y minuto de startTime */
        private void setKey() {
            String shortDate = 
                    String.format("%d-%d:%d", 
                                  date.getDayOfMonth(),
                                  startTime.getHour(),
                                  startTime.getMinute());

            key = LocalDateTime.parse(shortDate, keyFormatter);
        }

    }
```

En el método `setKey()` falla al intentar convertir el `String` en una fecha.

El fallo que da es:

```java
    Exception in thread "main" java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '15-11:45' could not be parsed at index 0
        at java.base/java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parseResolved0(DateTimeFormatter.java:2049)
        at java.base/java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parse(DateTimeFormatter.java:1951)
        at java.base/java.time.LocalDateTime.parse(LocalDateTime.java:492)
        at java.base/java.time.LocalDateTime.parse(LocalDateTime.java:477)
        at exercise9.Test.setKey(Test.java:60)
        at exercise9.Test.<init>(Test.java:34)
        at exercise9.App.main(App.java:15)
```

Comment: Mira `SimpleDateFormat`, es para cambiar el formato. Te dejo un enlace donde lo explican bien, puede servirte: https://guru99.es/java-date/

Comment: Pon un ejemplo de la entrada de datos. ¿Cómo le pasas la fecha y las horas? Estás usando el formato `dd-hh:mm` para formatear las horas. Entiendo que esto no es correcto porque no sabe qué hacer con las `dd`. Por eso te da la excepción _...could not be parsed at index 0_

Comment: El erro que tienes no lo puedo reproducir, pero realmente tu String.format está mal porque si el día es 1, hora 1  y minuto 1 te daría `1-1:1` cuando el formato debería de ser `01-01:01` ademas si la hora es 13 creo que te colocaría 1 porque `hh` debe de tener `pm-am` a diferencia de `HH` que son 0-23 horas, pero aparte de eso siempre te fallaría la conversión porque no puede convertir esa cadena a LocalDateTime, porque estas obligado a especificar todas las partes faltantes mes y año por ejemplo ya que el parse no funciona sin esas partes, porque no puede existir un día sin mes y año.

Comment: Es raro realizando un apruebas extras con ` 15-11:45` como se ve en tú error no falla con el mensaje `could not be parsed at index 0` , pero con `1-11:45` en el caso que el primer valor sea de un digito cuando debería ser `01-11:45` si es el mismo error, aparte de lo que ya te he expuesto en mi anterior comentario.

Answer (score 1):

Hola Manuel puedes probar con el siguiente código...

```
SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat( "dd-hh:mm");      
        System.out.println(simpleDateFormat.format(new Date()));
```

SimpleDateFormat proviene de  [java.text.SimpleDateFormat](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

Saludos...